# how to install ubuntu 12.04 with radeon tm hd 6470

Tags: gnome

i have hp pavilion g6 i5 laptop with Radoen hd 6470M switchable VGA. i installed it the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but VGA drivers doesn't work properly. i want to install drivers into the Ubuntu. 
please give good answer to instrall ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop probably has the ability to switch from on-board graphics to the 6470M (which I believe I understood from what you posted).

So from my understanding your 6470M drivers work but the VGA port graphics do not?

Look in `/var/log/jockey.log` and tell us what you see. If nothing "impressive" shows up, follow this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450 . It is very detailed so take your time going through it.

Comment: hi thakns ,but i coudnent fix my problem ,can u give ur skype id now

Comment: when i insert the cd ,no process in the laptop window